# How to fix javascript .toFixed is not a Function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here I am trying to add two decimal values in line `var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3);` and put the value in `var getSumTd = $("tr#sumTr").find("span#sumSpan");`.
But the problem is that `var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3);` throws an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: value.toFixed is not a function`.

Any help with my code will be great help.

Below is my script

```
<script>
$('button#value-plus').on('click', function () {
    debugger;
    var divUpd = $(this).closest("tr").find('#qnty');
    var subtotalcontainer = $(this).closest("tr").find('span#subtotal');
    var mainGrandTotalcontainer = $("tr#mainGtTr").find("#mainGt");
    var mainGtVal = parseFloat($("tr#mainGtTr").find('span#shippingCost').text());

    var getSumTd = $("tr#sumTr").find("span#sumSpan");
    var getShippingCost = parseFloat($("tr#mainGtTr").find('span#mainGt1').text());

    var bklId = $(this).closest("tr").find('#pid').val();
    var url = "/Product/incrementcart";
    $.getJSON(url, { prdid: bklId }, function (data) {
        debugger;
        divUpd.val(data.qty);
        var subTotal = data.qty * data.price;
        subtotalcontainer.text(subTotal.toFixed(2));

        var grandTotal = (mainGtVal + data.price).toFixed(3);
        mainGrandTotalcontainer.text(grandTotal);

        var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3);
        getSumTd.text(totalSum);

    }).success(function () {
        debugger
        var url = "/Product/cartupdate";
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            debugger;
            $(".shopping_button").html(data);
        })
    });
});
```

Below is my HTML

```
     <tbody>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ProductId, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "pid" })
                                <td data-title="Product Image &amp; name" class="t_md_align_c">
                                    <img src="images/quick_view_img_10.jpg" alt="" class="m_md_bottom_5 d_xs_block d_xs_centered">
                                    <a href="#" class="d_inline_b m_left_5 color_dark">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)</a>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="Stock">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Instock)
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="Price">
                                    <p class="f_size_large color_dark">$@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductPrice)</p>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="Quantity">
                                    <div class="clearfix quantity r_corners d_inline_middle f_size_medium color_dark m_bottom_10">
                                        <button class="bg_tr d_block f_left" data-direction="down" id="value-minus">-</button>
                                        <input type="text" name="" id="qnty" readonly value="@item.Quantity" class="f_left">
                                        <button class="bg_tr d_block f_left" data-direction="up" id="value-plus">+</button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="Subtotal">
                                    <p class="f_size_large fw_medium scheme_color">$<span id="subtotal">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Total)</span></p>
                                </td>
                                <td data-title="Remove">
                                    <a href="#" class="color_dark"><i class="fa fa-times f_size_medium m_right_5"></i>Remove</a><br>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        <tr id="mainGtTr">
                            <td colspan="4" class="v_align_m d_ib_offset_large t_xs_align_l">
                                <div class="d_ib_offset_0 d_inline_middle half_column d_xs_block w_xs_full m_xs_bottom_5">
                                    <button class="button_type_6 bg_scheme_color f_size_large r_corners tr_all_hover color_light m_bottom_20">Check Out </button>
                                </div>
                                <p class="fw_medium f_size_large t_align_r scheme_color p_xs_hr_0 d_inline_middle half_column d_ib_offset_normal d_xs_block w_xs_full t_xs_align_c">Grand Total:</p>
                            </td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="v_align_m">
                                <p class="fw_medium f_size_large scheme_color m_xs_bottom_10">$<span id="mainGt">@ViewBag.SubTotal</span></p>
                                <p style="font-style:oblique">Include <i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> <span id="shippingCost">@ViewBag.ShipingCost</span> shipping cost</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @{
                            var sum = ViewBag.SubTotal + ViewBag.ShipingCost;
                        }
                        <tr id="sumTr">
                            <td>
                                <span id="sumSpan">@sum</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: `grandTotal` is a string because it was constructed from `toFixed`, and strings do not have a `toFixed` method

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method formats a ***number***. The current value is of type ***string*** and instead of ***arithmetic addition***, ***string concatenation*** is happening. Convert those to ***number*** before adding:

Change:

```
var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3);
```

To

```
var totalSum = (Number(grandTotal) + Number(getShippingCost)).toFixed(3);
```

Answer (score 2):

[**toFixed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method is not available on `non-number` values. you need to parse value to [**Number**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) first than you can use `toFixed` method.

```js
let str = `123.123456`

console.log(Number(str).toFixed(3))
console.error(str.toFixed(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Only float, int value have `toFixed`. controle your variable and see which type are they.

```js
console.log(("4" + 5).toFixed(3)); // error

console.log((5 + 5).toFixed(3)); // yeep its working
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type of both the variables. They should be numeric and not strings. The method toFixed will not work for other data types. Also make sure when you convert the string to number, the value in string is internally a number like ‘22’ and not ‘hello’ as converting it to number may give you NaN and your program may fail.

Answer (score 0):

.toFixed() is only a function of a number and returns a string. By using toFixed in multiple assignments, you're turning a number into a string, concatenating multiple strings together, then trying to do a numerical operation on a string.

The following code will give an error.

```
var grandTotal = (mainGtVal + data.price).toFixed(3); // grandTotal is a string
var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3); // grandTotal + getShippingCost is a String, which doesn't have the toFixed function
```

If you need to avoid floating-point errors, then convert the string to a number before adding it to another number, for example:

```
var grandTotal = (mainGtVal + data.price).toFixed(3);
grandTotal = Number.parseFloat(grandTotal);
var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3);
```

Otherwise, wait until you're done with your calculations to use toFixed to round to the number of decimal places you want to display, for example:

```
var grandTotal = mainGtVal + data.price;
var totalSum = (grandTotal + getShippingCost).toFixed(3);
grandTotal = grandTotal.toFixed(3);
```